# How do I display validation errors with namespaces? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out how to do this.. I'm in the user-controller that's inside a namespace called admin, and this is how my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div class="reg-error">  
            <h4>Could not send registration!</h4>
            <ul>
                <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :rank %><br>
    <%= f.select :rank, options_for_select([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) %><br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Send registration", :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I'm using `[:admin, @user]` for the form, but it doesn't work with just replacing `@user.errors.any?` with `[:admin, @user].errors.any?`

The form it self works just fine, but it just won't display the validation errors.

How do I do this?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I didn't show you my controller, and I found the error there..

```
if @user.save
  UserMailer.invitation_mail(@user).deliver
  redirect_to admin_manage_users_path, :notice => "Successfully added a new account! Mail has been sent"
else
  @user = User.new
  @registered_users = User.where(:reg_key => nil)
  @pending_users = User.where("users.reg_key IS NOT NULL")
  render "show"
end
```

Since I had a `@user = User.new` in the else statement, It resetted the error messages some how. Totally missed that one. I'll leave it here if someone else would do this simple mistake too.. Thanks for the replys tho.

Comment: Did you try `<%= @user.errors %>` to see what the object looks like?

Comment: @mbratch Thanks for playing, but you're linking to a version of Rails that is about 4 years old (not counting patches).

Answer (score 0):

Try making just the following changes:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  if @user.errors.any?
    ...
    @user.errors_full_messages.each do |message|
      <li><%= message %></li>
```

If that doesn't work can you show me what your controller looks like.  For instance, in your users_controller new method are you doing something like:

```
@user = Admin::User.new
```

Comment: If I change `form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|` to `form_for @user do |f|` I get this error `undefined method `users_path'`, and then I specify the url of the form to `admin_users_path` to get the form workng again, but still no error messages. And I don't use a namespace for the model User, only the controller.

Comment: Tho.. In my controller in the else in if @user.save, I got this 

      `@user = User.new`
      `render "show"`

Could it be something like that `@user = User.new` resets error messages?

Comment: Thats in your create method right?  If so you are fine.  Are you namespacing in your routes.rb file.  Something like:  namespace :admin do resources :users end?

Comment: Just found the error.. It was the ` @user = User.new` in the else statement in the create action. A simple mistake, but now it works. Thanks for the help tho :)